# Zend Framework Send Mail either Text or Html

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hey I'm using something like this to send either a text mail or and html but it send both in the html version . What i'm doing wrong ? How can i do to send only text in case the email can't receive html ?

```
$htmlPart = new MimePart($htmlBody);
$htmlPart->type = "text/html";

$textPart = new MimePart($textBody);
$textPart->type = "text/plain";

$body = new MimeMessage();
$body->setParts(array($textPart, $htmlPart));

$message = new Message();
$message->addFrom($from, "My Corp.")
        ->addTo($email)
        ->setSubject(mb_convert_encoding($subject,"UTF-8"));
$message->setBody($body);
$message->setEncoding("UTF-8");
$options = /* … */
$transport = new SmtpTransport();
$transport->setOptions($options);
$transport->send($message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$message->getHeaders()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative');
```

after your `setBody()` call. Everything else looks okay. If it's still not working after that, please add some more information to your question about specifically what you're seeing in the email client.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Fountain that's what I forgot